# Always on Top, Window Manager Context Menu

Tags: window-manager

I have to hit Alt-Space to bring up the window manager menu that allows "always on top". Is this menu not accessible from the Window Decoration? There's no way to access it with the mouse?

I'm using the default window manager in Ubuntu 20.04. What is that called nowadays?;)

Comment: Right-click on window title?

Comment: Ah, Chrome overwrote the window manager, it seems. I had to click "Use system titlebar and borders";). Thanks